# heartbeat timeout error running rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, mailer, daemons, bunny

Running a Rails App in Mac. I start rabbit mq server in other terminal tab:

> $ rabbitmq-server

The I do staff within my Web App, and when the mail is supossed to be sent, I got this in **/usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log**

> =INFO REPORT==== 21-Apr-2015::23:02:47 ===
>
> accepting AMQP connection <0.4286.0> (127.0.0.1:57509 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)
>
> =ERROR REPORT==== 21-Apr-2015::23:02:50 ===
>
> closing AMQP connection <0.4286.0> (127.0.0.1:57509 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
>   {heartbeat_timeout,running}

Notes:

I left all rabbitmq configuration as default, with this I mean in **mailer.rb:**

> ```
>  :heartbeat => 10
> ```

The same configuration work perfectly in Ubuntu.

Comment: Please post your full RabbitMQ config and some code.